# React Native Expo - stuck at "downloading javascript bundle"

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

This is insanely annoying. I have been working on a project for the past 1 week and absolutely no issue. All of a sudden, Expo decided to do this. It says "downloading javascript bundle" at 100%, yet it will not load my app. On my terminal it says

```
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 1319ms.
Running application on AOSP on IA Emulator.
```

I have reinstalled expo-cli and also expo on my emulator. Nothing works.

Please help. This is frustrating as **I have been using expo for a while, with no issue at all. Normally when this happens I just restart my emulator and everything works fine.** And then now....it is always stuck at "downloading javascript bundle"....

If I use my real phone, it says

```
Something went wrong. Could not load exp:/xxx.xxx.xx.exp.direct:80
```

**I noticed this happened after installing expo-image-picker. Could this be the reason why?** I uninstalled expo-image-picker but the issue is still here.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution 1:

This issue is because of any dependency that you have added into your project.
you can try removing last package that you have install.

#### Solution 2:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm start -- --reset-cache
npm install
```

#### Solution 3:

use `yarn` instead of `npm`, and always install the package using  `expo install your_package_name` by this it will resolve version of package and install version which is compatible with `expo`

Comment: After being stuck for hours I deleted the node_modules & re-installed them, and the app is running again. Thank you